# Не срабатывает JsonRootName (Jackson)

Tags: root, jackson

Не работает JsonRootName

pojo

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonRootName;

@JsonRootName(value = "request")
public class RequestBean {

    private String order_id;
    private int merchant_id;
    private String order_desc;
}
```

тест

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
        RequestBean req = new RequestBean();
        req.setMerchant_id(1396338);
        req.setOrder_desc("desc");
        req.setOrder_id("132");
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(req);
        System.out.println(json);

    }
}
```

ожидается

```
{
  "request":{
    "order_id":"test8037875286",
    "order_desc":"Test payment",
    "merchant_id":"1"
  }
}
```

получается

```
{
  "RequestBean":{
    "order_id":"test8037875286",
    "order_desc":"Test payment",
    "merchant_id":"1"
  }
}
```

dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы смешиваете зависимости для Jackson 1.x и Jackson 2.x. Вот рабочий вариант:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
    RequestBean req = new RequestBean();
    req.setMerchant_id(1396338);
    req.setOrder_desc("desc");
    req.setOrder_id("132");
    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(req);
    System.out.println(json);
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
    <!-- the core, which includes Streaming API, shared low-level abstractions (but
        NOT data-binding) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Just the annotations; use this dependency if you want to attach annotations
        to classes without connecting them to the code. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- databinding; ObjectMapper, JsonNode and related classes are here -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Да спасибо! Именно в этом проблема! кстати работает даже если в dependencies оставить только последнюю зависимость так как она включает в себя первые две